# How can I send home personal information from work?

Tags: documentation

What is the best method of transferring documents from my work laptop to my home laptop?

I frequently want to bring home documents from work. These are generally either:

1. **Paystubs**

   - Only available through the online portal, via the company network.
2. **Web links**

   - links to books/articles that I want to read later
   - Stack exchange posts I want to read, but shouldn't be doing so on company time

My workplace has a fairly generic (and therefore restrictive) policy on not transferring internal documents from work laptops to personal laptops or storage drives, for the common/obvious reasons.

I have in the past just been emailing these things to my personal email account. In my mind this leaves an appropriate paper trail to show that I have not been sending company documents home (versus e.g. a USB stick which I can copy anything to, transparently). Does this cover my liability effectively or should I talk with my manager about a different method of moving these things to my personal data hoard?

ETA: As well, how should I manage the situations frequently mentioned on this site where it is advised to "Keep a copy of that email offsite", to document an interaction with or instructions from a superior?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99089/discussion-on-question-by-jsarbour-how-to-send-home-personal-information-from-wo).

Comment: The only people who can give you an authoritative answer to this question are your manager, HR and/or IT departments.  Nobody on the internet can possibly know what your company policies are - this question should probably just be closed.

Comment: Does this policy say anything about paystubs?

Comment: If you ask your manager, HR and/or IT, make sure to restrict your question to the paystubs. You should be allowed to have a copy of those for your personal administration, but you can't make a strong case for the other items.

Comment: For your ETA - **attach** a copy of the email (rather than just forwarding) to a personal account, or set up a oneDrive/googleDocs folder and save a copy there

Answer (score 34):

> My workplace has a fairly generic (and therefore restrictive) policy on not transferring **internal documents** from work laptops to personal laptops or storage drives, for the common/obvious reasons.

You need to find out what the bolded expression actually means.

In most organisations, this interpretation would exclude:

- Links to commonly available data
- Documents relating to your employment
- Personal documents (though your IT policy may prohibit non-work related material)

Usually what is meant is specifically intellectual property.

If you are unclear, speak to your manager.

Comment: IANAL, but I'd also add that paystubs can be considered tax documents, so you're entitled to have a copy for your personal records and tax filing, depending on the country.

Comment: Paystubs should not be on the work computer, it is not good for that information to be shared, and there is a risk they might be.

Comment: @mckenzm: How does a digital paystub somehow suggest that it's intended for sharing, more than a paper paystub? Furthermore, I can steal an envelope more easily than I can gain unlawful access to a secured server. There is nothing wrong with digital paystubs, nor is there with a secure delivery platform for said digital paystub (from server to company-owned machine). But as Juliana addresses, the employee does need to be able to transfer the file on from there (where culturally applicable).

Comment: @Flater I think mckenzm is suggesting, probably correctly, that your boss can give anyone access to "your" computer to complete work. Like if you're away sick for a day, away on vacation etc. someone else can use it. Basically, the file system on the computer is not the same as a personal locker, which would be the analogy in physical sense. If you have personally sensitive documents (like payslips), it shouldn't live on the PC.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: There are many steps you (or mckenzm) have jumped over to get to that conclusion. (1) Providing access to a **user account** (not just a machine) is not reasonable other than for an employee who is permanently unavailable (quit, fired, deceased), and even then it's an arguable point (illegal where I'm from). (2) The paystubs are accessible via an online portal, which means that either OP has separate credentials for this portal (which are still unknown even with Windows user account access), or OP's Windows credentials are also their credentials to HR related forms [..]

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: [..] which would make providing access to OP's Windows account a massive misstep by whoever granted an unknown actor access to OP's confidential information and makes the company (or person, depending on the source of the transgresstion) open to legal prosecution.

Comment: @Flater The computer is not a personal computer. It belongs to the workplace. Where are you from where you think this is illegal? I think it's actually you who are making bold assumptions about how the computer is shared.

Comment: For instance, you are assuming a Windows PC, you are assuming that the user account is shared (not just the PC), you are assuming that the user will not be an admin on the computer (which is reasonably common in some environments). You are assuming that the OP is located where you are, and subject to the same laws (from what I can gather, the OP is situated in Canada, if that helps).

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: I never argued that the computer is a personal computer. The user account and the computer are two completely different things. Privacy **can** be restricted to the **user account**, not the machine. If the user account is not privacy protected, then it should not be used as the communication platform for confidential information as others could indeed get access to this account. But there's no confirmation from OP on this privacy point either way at the moment.  Also, how do you suggest local admin rights would provide access to another user's account on an online portal?

Comment: @Flater I'm aware the user account and the computer are two different things, which is why I said computer, and not user account. Note that there is almost certainly no "law" preventing user account access to be given to others. It would almost certainly come down to the expectation of privacy, which is a more general concept. If the work policy is that the computer is not to be used for personal things, there is no reasonable expectation of privacy. In answering your question, I didn't suggest that.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie `If the work policy is that the computer is not to be used for personal things there is no reasonable expectation of privacy` Being required to use a work account to access your confidential HR information **requires privacy**. Without user account privacy (of the **online portal** user account, not necessarily the OS user account), the confidentiality of the HR documents is violated.

Comment: @Flater Which is why you should log in and out of online portals when you go to use them, and not store personal information on your workstation.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: Reread my comments and realize I never even remotely suggested anything about storing files or personal information on a machine. OP's account which is required to access their confidential HR documents on the online portal (**regardless** of whether that is OS user account based or a completely separate portal user account) **must** be privacy protected as it grants access to confidential information. Which machine OP uses to connect to the portal **does not matter in any way**.

Comment: @Flater This whole discussion because you wanted to dispute someone who said: "Paystubs should not be on the work computer, it is not good for that information to be shared, and there is a risk they might be.".  If you were not responding to that, I'm sorry, I have misinterpreted you. But you should really not @ someone unless you are responding to what they said, cause it can get mighty confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99091/discussion-between-gregory-currie-and-flater).

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: I responded to the comment that stated digital paystubs are somehow inherently a bad idea "because paystubs shouldn't be shared". At no point did I say that the paystubs should be stored on the machine, but rather than they should be able to be _sent onwards from_ that machine (e.g. OP forwarding them to their personal email address or personal USB stick). I wasn't discussing that they should be _stored_ on the work machine (other than downloading them temporarily so you can forward/copy them of course - but again not the focus of my response)

Comment: @Flater Nobody said digital pay-stubs are bad, which I attempted to clarify when you initially had the false impression about that being said.

Answer (score 12):

**Paystubs**

Speak with the HR department. They may be able to see if this stuff can be emailed to you. While the Paystubs are work-related, they are not work IP, and need to be available to you even when you're not at work.

**links to books/articles that I want to read later**

Create a google account, or your equivalent browsers account, for this purpose and save bookmarks as you usually would. It should synchronize wherever you use that account. The benefit of this approach is you are not sending arbitrary data to yourself, but just saving URLs to "the cloud".

Before installing anything, make sure it is acceptable via work policy. If you want to be cautious, ask the IT department if they mind you log in to your personal account at work. (So that bookmarks can be synchronized).

Comment: While I agree that it would be best to ask HR to send me paystubs externally directly, I do not think that having a google account linked to my work browser and accessing it from outside of work would be a good solution. That feels to me like crossing data boundaries that shouldn't be crossed.

Comment: Just for the record, and looking at where you work, I doubt you need to be quite as concerned with this as you appear to be. If security was such a concern you would have an air-gapped PC to work on. But it doesn't hurt to discuss with your manger as others have suggested.

Comment: My paystubs can only be emailed to my work account, and I've been leery of emailing them unencrypted to my home email.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I would be concerned. Yes normally there will be no problem but it does give the company a way to say you broke the rules and so can fire for cause.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek How can you send the pay slip information to the IRS/HMRC or other tax authorities? If you complete your tax form you will not be using your work email as you might leave the work during the year or do other work

Comment: @Mark From the company I get a printed form for taxes at the end of the year.  That is separate from the twice monthly pay stubs that are only available via email (and pay is direct deposit).

Comment: Pay stubs are not work related. They are related to your employment contract, not your work. Think about it: The company can give anything work related to your manager or a colleague. They can’t give your payslips to your manager or a colleague.

Comment: Creating a browser account is a terrible advice. Unlike email, browser sync is automatic and bidirectional, so it's easy both to leak sensitive data, such as passwords, and to bring some undesired information inside the corporate network.

Comment: @IMil Indeed. I originally used my personal Google account at my first job, but I stopped doing that and fully switched to a separate account for my work Chrome after inappropriate urls I perused at home started to appear on my work PC.

Comment: @Nzall We've all been there. Which is why I suggested a separate account.

Comment: Agree - a sync bookmark feature is a bad idea, but there are "save for later" type of bookmarks (eg firefox's pocket) that would be much more suitable that you could also retrieve to read at home as well as the obvious feature of saving them to read later at work.

Comment: With this solution, OP is not only sending this data to his private machine, he's potentially handing it over to 3rd parties. So the risk if found out only increases. While the risk of being found out *may* decrease (that highly depends on the mechanisms the workplace uses to counter data sharing), if OP answers why he did that he cannot answer truthfully ("so you don't find out I'm sending stuff home") or looks even more like he's intentionally breaking security protocols. Just apply the paystub solution to everything: ask and clarify what the proper procedure is.

Comment: @gbjbaanb What is the difference between bookmark sync and save for later bookmarks?

Comment: @IMil It's easy, but fortunately also configurable. At least for Chrome, you can configure what is shared, to only allow for bookmarks. I don't believe a properly configured browser account is any more risky than logging into your work email from home

Comment: @Mars the direction of data ... as mentioned elsewhere, you don't want some personal stuff (all those links to jobs boards for example) getting synced to your work account.

Answer (score 5):

I see 3 issues here:

1. When you transfer data, management may erroneously think that you are stealing proprietary company information.
2. Some means of transferring data may create security problems.
3. Management may frown on taking time off from actual work to save information for personal use.

Let me address #3 first. In real life, employees have to spend some amount of time on things like filling out tax forms and reviewing pay stubs. I've never worked for a company that said that you weren't allowed to look at your pay stub on "company time". So let's assume that's a non-issue unless your management is totally draconian, in which case you have bigger problems than how to get your pay stub home.

I could imagine a company saying that they don't want you to spend time at work looking at non-work related web sites. (Like Stack Exchange? Oops.) In any job I've ever had, it's not uncommon to be looking for something work-related on the Internet, notice something peripheral that I find interesting, and spend a few minutes looking at that. At times it gets out of hand and I spend an hour on something that's really just for my personal amusement, and the company would legitimately consider that a problem. But really, if I'm looking for information on, say, how to get a database query I'm working on to function correctly, and along the way I see an ad for some product I might want to buy and spend 10 minutes reading about the product, normally no one cares. It's no different from if I spent 10 minutes chatting with a co-worker. So I doubt the company would object to me sending the link to myself to read at home rather than reading it on company time. So as long as you're not spending hours saving off personal data, let's assume that's not the issue either.

Some ways to get data home might create a security risk, at least theoretically. Like someone mentioned that there might be a virus on your thumb drive that you're now putting on the network. I think email yourself information should be as safe as it's going to get. I don't think you can get a virus by SENDING an email, and if you could, I don't see why there would be more danger emailing your own personal account than emailing a client.

As to management worrying that you're stealing proprietary information: I don't doubt that some managers would say this, but I think they're being irrational. Not that it's irrational to be concerned about proprietary information, but that it's irrational to be suspicious any time an employee saves data. There are many completely legitimate reasons for an employee to take data home. Your pay stub example is an obvious one. They can't tell you that you're not allowed to take your pay stubs home. So whatever you do to transport the data, how do they know whether you're only taking data you can legitimately take and not stealing something? Other than by examining the contents of your emails or your thumb drive or your print-outs, or by having some sort of monitoring system that tracks every time a file is copied, or something of that sort, I don't know how they could know.

Every time an employee walks into the supply room to get a pad of paper or a stapler, he MIGHT be stealing company supplies. But most companies conclude that guarding against this possibility is not worth the cost. Yes, some companies have people assigned to manage the supply room and employees can't just walk in and get a stapler, they have to fill out a request form and get it approved and then have an authorized person take it off the shelf and give it to them. But most companies conclude that the cost of all this is way more than the losses do to pilferage and don't bother. Likewise, a company could monitor every email employees send to make sure that they aren't emailing proprietary information to competitors, but I've never heard of a company doing this, because it would be too time-consuming and expensive.

So short answer: Emailing it to yourself is probably the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

> My workplace has a fairly generic (and therefore restrictive) policy on not transferring internal documents from work laptops to **personal** laptops or **storage** drives, for the common/obvious reasons.

Your personal email is a personal storage space, albeit not physical, so this seems like a really bad idea in general.

Also, since the company provides you with a laptop, why do you need to transfer the files to your personal one? You should use the company's provided equipment if you need to work remotely.

However, if you really want to do this, and since company policies vary wildly, I'd suggest speaking with your manager so you can get an explicit and approved way of going about it (in which case you should request them to send you said info by email and not verbally) or an explicit message to stop it (in which case you should most definitely stop it).

Comment: The OP details what types of documents they want to bring home, and they are not work-related documents. The suggestion to work from home is irrelevant and not helpful.

Comment: The OP says they need their payslips. Those should not be on company equipment as they are your documents, not your employer and may be legally relevant and required for one to have for tax purposes.

Comment: Pay stubs are _not_ "internal company documents" and the employee has as much of a right to their own copy of them as the company does. They are legally-required tax records belonging to the employee.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure I did write this tool, but it's completely free to use. No ads or tracking etc.

I faced the same problem and wrote a Chrome extension to save a backlog of links. Originally it was a ghetto playlist creator where I could queue up a load of stuff to watch and just click next, but it will work for your need of storing web links.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-queue/abjpbboagegjdkhehcblbaodcedegdce?hl=en

Source code is here: https://github.com/james-gould/TabQueue/

If you can sign into Chrome on your work computer it will sync the saved links to your Chrome account, which you'll be able to access from home.

In terms of pay stubs, can you not request your payroll department to send it to a 2nd email address? I get digtial-only payslips and they're sent to both my work and personal email accounts by my request.

Answer (score -3):

## Stack Exchange posts I want to read...

You can "favourite" questions by clicking on the star:

[image: Favourite star]

They will then appear in the [Favorites tab on your Activity page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/105929/jsarbour?tab=favorites).

Comment: Good point, though it does require using the same SE account at work and home. Certainly not a bad option, though perhaps inadvisable. I was hoping to address the more general case of "interesting web links" with SE posts as an example, rather than SE posts specifically.